# What is the Seller Registration Number on a Bill of Sale?

Tags: registration

I am selling a car in Ohio and downloaded the generic Bill of Sale form from this website: http://www.dmv.org/images/bill-of-sale.pdf

Does anyone know what the Seller Registration Number field is used for? Is it my driver's license number, license plate number, or something else entirely?

I went on Ohio's BMV website to check my vehicle registration (https://www.oplates.com/Home/LoginVR?returnUrl=%2FVR%2FPlate%2FCheckRegistrationSelect), but the only number provided is the license plate number?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a localized regulatory issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ohio unlike other states a bill of sale is not required. The car should have a title and that title is on file at the title bureau. You will fill the title out and take it to a notary to get signed. Exchange the title and car for the money. The new owner will take the title to the title bureau and pay the sales tax on the price filled out on the title to get a new title with their name.

The bill of sale you have listed seems to be a generic one. I would put private party under seller registration number field. The bill of sale is most likely for use with dealers or resellers that posses such a number.

Comment: Understood, thank you! I am sorry if this question is off-topic; this seemed like the best site for such an inquiry.